# Image-Processing using Action Camera through Wi-fi in raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, object-detection, video-processing, drone.io

I want to detect human using my drone's action camera. But I haven't found any similar video or resource. Mainly the action wifi camera will capture the real time video. This action camera haven't any IP address , it's use an app to view the real time video.

**How can I feed this video to my human detecting model or code?**

Please help me..(as I will use low budget action camera because of budget issue like "Akaso EK7000 or Akaso brave 7 wi-fi supported Action camera)

It's my Microprocessor project so I need to use Raspberry pi 4 for image processing .What other method can I use ? Is there any other way ?

I am searching internet. but nothing found. My brain is not working how to do it. Maybe it's happening.